# Property 'endDate' does not exist on type on the component

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular-directive

Property `endDate` does not exist on type `TestComponent`

```
test.Component.cs
```

--

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import {Message} from 'primeng/api';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  selector: 'test',
  providers:[TestService]
})
export class TestComponent  {
    public testingForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private userService: UserService,
        ,private formBuilder: FormBuilder
      ) { 
        console.log("Inside constructor...");
      }
      
      ngOnInit():void {  
           console.log("Inside onNotify ...."); 
           this.testingForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            startDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required), 
            endDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required), 
            message: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
           });     
           this.loadData();       
      }
      
      ...////.....
      
      
      }
```

--

```
test.component.html
```

--

```
<form [formGroup]="testingForm"  >
<div>
<label class="control-label col-sm-4">Start Date:</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <p-calendar formControlName="endDate" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar><span style="margin-left:35px">{{endDate|date}}</span>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

`app.module.ts`  - has the `formModule` imported

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Below is the error I'm getting:

```
 ERROR in src/testing/test.component.html:37:115 - error TS2339: Property 'endDate' does not exist on type 'testingComponent'.

    37             <p-calendar formControlName="endDate" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar><span style="margin-left:35px">{{endDate|date}}</span>
                                                                                                                         ~~~~~~~

      src/testing/test.component.ts:19:16
        19   templateUrl: './test.component.html',
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component TestComponent.
```

Any input is highly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, it doesn't.

You can, for example, add the getter to extract it from the FormGroup:

```
get endDate(): Date {
    return this.testingForm ? this.testingForm.value.endDate : null;
}
```

Comment: i see the error durng compilation though runtime displays the calendar. I am not that far in submitting the page.

Comment: Yes, the dev server is more lenient than the production build.